# $0$ is an stable equilibrium of $x' = Ax$ iff $A$ is semisimple, given that all of its eigenvalues have real part 0.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

$0$ is an stable equilibrium of $x' = Ax$ iff $A$ is semisimple, given that all of its eigenvalues have real part 0.

I'm kind of confused here: I had understood that if all of the eigenvalues of $A$ have real part 0 then the origin is an stable equilibrium of $x' = Ax$. That is because $A$ is a combination of rotations on different, linearly-independent subspaces.

What's wrong in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not all real matrices with purely imaginary eigenvalues are combinations of rotations; that is only true for some [normal matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).  Also, if a normal matrix has a purely imaginary eigenvalue, it is a $90^\circ$ rotation followed by a scaling map.

More relevantly to the question at hand, not all real matrices with purely imaginary eigenvalues are diagonalizable (i.e. "semisimple").  As a counterexample, consider the matrix
$$
A = 
\pmatrix{
0&-1&1&0\\
1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&-1\\
0&0&1&0
}
$$
Whose eigenvalues are $\pm i$.  For systems with matrices like these, we need to study the behavior of generalized eigenvectors.